# How do you use NSBundle pathForResource without autorelease pool?

Tags: objective-c, autorelease, nsbundle

What is the non-autorelease equivalent of this code?

> NSString *nsFName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nsName
>   ofType:nsExt inDirectory:nsPath];

Comment: Why don't you have an autorelease pool in place? There should always be a top-level pool in Cocoa. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Comment: this code is running on a separate thread

Comment: You should be setting up your own pool, then. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW16

Comment: In my case, these threads don't last long, and may be spawned in large numbers...in that case, wouldn't it be wasteful creating autorelease pools for every one?

Comment: You should probably be looking into alternatives to explicit thread use, then; at this point they are a tool of last resort in Cocoa. Take a gander at the [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/); it sounds like using a GCD queue would suit your needs.

Comment: unfortunately, this isn't just for cocoa. It's c++ code that has to maintain an interface compatible with android/windows as well

Comment: Then you have to set up a pool. There's no way around not having an autorelease pool per thread if you're using Cocoa; even if _you_ don't use any methods that create autoreleased objects, internal code may.

Comment: ok. I think I may be confused though...does the autorelease pool actually allocate any memory up front? or is it just objective-c's way of handling something like a c++ shared_ptr?

Comment: An autorelease pool is an object, yes, although with the latest few compilers
 it's private, and we just use `@autoreleasepool{//code here}`. It maintains a list of objects (that it owns), and sends `release` to each of them when it is drained.

Comment: awesome, thanks. I Thought the autorelease pool was pre-allocating a fixed amount of memory every time, not just storing a bunch of references to things that need to be destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one. When you're using Cocoa, [you must have a pool in place](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html):

> Cocoa always expects there to be an autorelease pool available. If a pool is not available, autoreleased objects do not get released and your application leaks memory. If you send an autorelease message when a pool is not available, Cocoa logs a suitable error message.

Part of the GUI application set-up process is establishing one on the main thread; non-GUI programs need to create one as well.

If you're creating your own threads, you [need to create and manage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW16) an autorelease pool for each of those threads as well:

> Applications that link in Objective-C frameworks typically must create at least one autorelease pool in each of their threads. If an application uses the managed model—where the application handles the retaining and releasing of objects—the autorelease pool catches any objects that are autoreleased from that thread.

Depending on what else you are doing, you may be able to use CoreFoundation. There's a CFType, `CFBundle`, on which `NSBundle` is built. It has a function `CFBundleCopyResourceURL()` that may do what you need. If you can translate all your code to Core Foundation, then you can escape using a pool, although -- as Ken says -- it's really not the burden that you think it is. You're probably hitting the disk every time you use `pathForResource:ofType:` anyways.

Comment: +1 and I'll add that concerns about the "expense" of setting up and tearing down an autorelease pool are misplaced. They're just [not that expensive](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/autorelease-is-fast.html) and are even cheaper now with `@autoreleasepool`. The cost is surely dwarfed by even `-[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]` let alone creating and tearing down **threads** "in large numbers"(!).